# Using Firebase messaging on IOS in XCode 9

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app crashes the simulator every time I try to run with the following message.

> Function boringssl_context_get_peer_sct_list: line 1757 received sct
>   extension length is less than sct data length

I'm not sure the cause, but I would love feedback on the proper ORDER for the following 3 lines:

```
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self  
// IOS 9 
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

or

```
// IOS10
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the best way to do it.**

Request Permission first, Once We get approval, then Register for push Notifications

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in

        print("permision granted \(granted)")

        guard granted else { return }

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification Settings \(settings)")
            guard settings.authorizationStatus == .authorized else { return }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // register
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }

        }
    }
```